# Let a and b be natural numbers that are co-prime. Prove that (b-a) and b must also be co-prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

If gcd(a,b)=1 then gcd(b-a,b)=1. I'm kind of lost... Any hint or advice on how to start this proof?

Thanks!

Comment: I would show you some URLs:1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity (tells you how to find $\gcd(a,b)$ ) 2)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers (tells you the case that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ )

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $d$ divides $b-a$ and also divides $b$. This means that $d$ divides their diffence $b- (b-a)=a$ as well. So $d$ divides $a$ and $b$ hence their gcd...

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=(b-a,b)$. Then $d | b$ and $d | a$. Since the only positive divisor of $a$ and $b$ is $1$, $d=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=\gcd(b-a,b)$. Suppose $b-a=dc_1$ and $b=dc_2$， where $\gcd(c_1,c_2)=1$. Then
$$a=-(b-a)+b=-dc_1+dc_2=d(c_2-c_1).$$
So $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$. It follows from the definition of $\gcd$ that $d\mid \gcd(a,b)=1$. It must have $d=1$, i.e., $\gcd(b-a,b)=1$.